# Questions on Neutral oxides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

Neutral oxides, are non metal oxides which are neither acidic nor basic.
I have noticed a pattern for neutral oxides which I am unsure actually holds true.

$\ce{CO}$, $\ce{H2O}$, $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{N2O}$ are examples of neutral oxides. It seems that neutral oxides will always have 1 oxygen atom. While non metal oxides with more than 1 oxygen atom     seems to always be acidic oxide. ($\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{SO3}$, $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{P4O10}$).

Is this a coincidence? Are there any neutral oxides with more than one oxygen atom?

Comment: This is just a coincidence. Besides, H2O is not neutral; it is both acidic and basic, which might seem to be the same, but in fact is quite different.

Comment: And, $\ce{NO}$ is not just $\ce{NO}$.  It will contain a little dimer, $\ce{N2O2}$, which is still neutral.

Comment: Hmm, Since N2O2 is a neutral oxide, then it disproves the "all neutral oxides have 1 oxygen atom". However, the empirical formula of N2O2 is NO.  Is C2O2 and N4O2 neutral also? If they are neutral also, maybe the empirical formula of a neutral oxide will always have oxygen with a ratio of 1 to the other components.

Comment: Do not get hung up on this.  $\ce{Cl2O}$ is acidic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cl2O has one oxygen atom and is an acidic oxide. Thus, not all non metal oxides with one oxygen atom are neutral oxide. Also, not all neutral oxides have only one oxygen atom. [N2O2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitrogen_dioxide), a neutral oxide but has more than one oxygen atom.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, where nonmetallic oxides have a relatively low oxidation state of the nonmetallic you are more likely to get a neutral or only weakly acidic oxide. Usually this means only one oxygen atom in the molecule. Adding more oxygen atoms would make the nonmetallic atom centers more electrophilic towards water,which then shows up as greater acidity. Thereby, for instance, $\ce{CO2}$ would be expected to show greater acidity than $\ce{CO}$.

Carbon suboxide. $\ce{C3O2}$, shows am0hoteric character, reacting as an acid with water and ammonia but also deprotonating hydrogen chloride; in these reactions malonic acid or its derivatives are produced[[1](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-814369-8.00013-3)].

**Reference**

1. James E. House (2020). Chapter 13, *Chemistry of nonmetallic elements I. Hydrogen, boron, oxygen, and carbon* (Third Edition), Academic Press,
   2020,
   Pages 465-516,
   ISBN 9780128143698,
   https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-814369-8.00013-3.