# Difference between neutral and amphoteric oxides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, terminology

What is actual difference between neutral oxides (e.g. $\ce{NO},$ $\ce{N2O},$ $\ce{CO})$ and amphoteric oxides (e.g. $\ce{Al2O3})?$ I got a hint of it from [the comment of Ivan Neretin](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/109508/68148).

Answer (score 2):

Neutral oxides do not manifest either acidic either alkalic behaviour ( but eventually very weak in extremely alkalic/acidic environment).

Amphoteric oxides manifest, more or less balanced, both behaviours in reasonably strong acidic/alkalic environments.